# django {% if user.groups == 'FC' %} doens't work

Tags: django

I'm making a website using django.

{% if user.groups == 'FC' %} doesn't work in my template.I have groups like that.

[image: my user group]

For example, one of my users(username is 'hong) belongs to 'FC' group as you see below.
   [image]

But,

```
{% if user.groups == 'FC' %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'register' %}">register form</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'mypage' %}">fc's my page</a></li>
{% else %}
 <li><a href="{% url 'PT_mypage' %}">fitness' my page</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

if user.groups == ' '  doesn't work.

How I check the users' group? I have to distinguish the users by groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `tags`.
In your application, you can create a directory which is named : `templatetags`.

Then, you have to create inside a file `user_tags.py` which will contain :

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group 

register = template.Library() 

@register.filter(name='has_group') 
def has_group(user, group_name):
    group = Group.objects.filter(name=group_name)
    if group:
        group = group.first()
        return group in user.groups.all()
    else:
        return False
```

Then, in your template, if you want to specify part, ...

```
{% load user_tags %}
...
...
{% if request.user|has_group:"yourgroupe" %}
# part which will only accessible for users registered in `yourgroup` 
{% endif %}
```

It works in my application with different groups (admin, users, visitors, ..) ;)

Comment: It works! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

try below

```
{% for group in  request.user.groups.all %}
{%  if 'FC' == group.name %}
   <<< write your code that you want >>>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is this the best solution?

Comment: What if a user has more than 1 group?

Comment: It does double if it is 2 groups.

Comment: but group has same name two times? @DerekPK

Comment: Different groups 2 times, group0 then group1 etc. I can't then check if a user has 2 groups, it will return false. `if 'group0' == group.name and 'group1' == group.name`, a user who has group0 and group1 will still return false.

Comment: We’re itrating groups from users. So will return user groups