# Filter by Users Group

Tags: django

I only want to show buttons based on a user group. In this example I have a list of buttons then an IF Statement that checks if the user is in the group 'Recruiter', if they are then it displays some additional buttons:

Is there an easier way to do this in the html, like
`{% if request.user.groups == 'recruiter' %}`

Views.py

```
fields = request.user.groups
if fields == 'Recruiter':
        fields1 = 'True'
else: fields1 = ''

context['fields1'] = fields1
```

html

```
{% if fields1 %}
a bunch of buttons
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Here is the answer you want. Check his answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44983959/django-if-user-groups-fc-doenst-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# request.user.groups.all will return queryset, so you have iterate on the queryset in order to compare the group 'Recruiter'

{% for group in request.user.groups.all %}
    {% if group.name == 'Recruiter' %}
    a bunch of buttons
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

OR

# if you already know that you have only group assigned to the user, then you directly compare the group 'Recruiter'

{% if request.user.groups.all.0.name == 'Recruiter' %}
    a bunch of buttons
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Excellent. While I couldn't get your example to work exactly, you got me on the right path. In the end I just used 

{% if user.groups == 'Recruiter' %}
a bunch of buttons
{% endif %}

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you talk about the groups from django auth module, you can create a custom template tag for that:

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library() 

@register.filter(name='in_group') 
def in_group(user, name):
    return user.groups.filter(name=name).exists()
```

Than in your template:

```py
{% if request.user|in_group:"thegroup" %} 
    // Put here the buttons you want
{% else %}
    // put here what is for everybody
{% endif %}
```